# group sections of Jenkinsfile in functions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I have a Jenkins pipelines that works, but Sonar is complaining because the depth of the nested blocks is too high

I don't see an easy way to reduce the number of blocks so I'd like to do something like creating a function for it, but my attempts to do that have failed.

I'd like to convert something like:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage {
            parallel {
                 stage{
                       steps {
                               script {
                               }
                       }
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

into

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage {
            parallelized_stages()
            
        }
     }
}

def parallelize_stages() {
    parallel {
         stage{
              steps {
                     script {
                     }
               }
         }
     }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Following is an example.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelJobs()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def parallelJobs() {
  return [
      a: { 
        stage('Test1') {
            echo "Stage 1"
        }
      },
      b: { 
        stage('Test2') {
            echo "Stage 2"
        }
      }
      ]
}
```